# Flickering rectangle pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I created button with pygame.draw.rect which I use to scroll background so it looks like the character(black rectangle) is moving.
But when I click any of the button all the buttons flicker.
How can I solve it

```
import sys
import time
pygame.init()

width = 2000
height = 3000

bg= pygame.image.load("bg1.jpg")
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg,(width,height))
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = False

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None ,101)

class npc:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
        pygame.draw.rect(display,(125,125,125),(self.x, self.y ,100,200))
        
        

def ts(string):
    text = ''
    for i in range(len(string)):
        
        
        
        text += string[i]
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (width/2, height/2)
        
        display.fill((130,190,255), text_rect)
        
        display.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
        
        
        pygame.time.wait(100)
        

p_x = 50
p_y = height/2 + 178
bgx = 0
bgx2 = bg.get_width()

bgy = 0
bgy2 = bg.get_height()

def move():
    
    global bgx
    global bgx2

    bgx -= 50
    bgx2 -= 50
    
    display.blit(bg ,[bgx,bgy])
    display.blit(bg, [bgx2,bgy2])
    
def movex():
    global bgx
    global bgx2
    bgx += 50
    bgx2 += 50
    
    display.blit(bg ,[bgx,bgy])
    display.blit(bg, [bgx2,bgy2])
    
def move_2():
    global bgy
    global bgy2
    
    bgy -= 50
    bgy2 -= 50
    
    display.blit(bg ,[bgx,bgy])
    display.blit(bg, [bgx2,bgy2])
    
def movey():
    global bgy
    global bgy2
    
    bgy += 50
    bgy2 += 50
    
    display.blit(bg ,[bgx,bgy])
    display.blit(bg, [bgx2,bgy2])
    
fun = [movey ,move_2 ,movex ,move]


while not run:
    
    

    btn1 = pygame.Rect(210,110,110,110)
    btn2 = pygame.Rect(210,420,110,110)
    btn3 = pygame.Rect(95,265,110,110)
    btn4 = pygame.Rect(325,265,110,110)
    
    btn = [btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4]
    
    

    
    
    mouse_pos = (0,0)
    
    
    if bgy > bg.get_height():
        bgy = bg.get_height() * -1
        
    if bgy2 > bg.get_height():
        bgy2= bg.get_height() * -1
        
    if bgy < bg.get_height() * -1:
        bgy = bg.get_height()
        
    if bgy2 < bg.get_height() * -1:
        bgy2 = bg.get_height()
    
    
    if bgx < bg.get_width() * -1:
        bgx = bg.get_width()
        
    if bgx2 < bg.get_width() * -1:
        bgx2 = bg.get_width()
        
    if bgx > bg.get_width():
        bgx = bg.get_width() * -1
        
    if bgx2 >= bg.get_width():
        bgx2 = bg.get_width() * -1
        

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit_game = True
            
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = event.pos
            
    display.blit(bg ,[bgx,bgy])
    display.blit(bg ,[bgx2,bgy2])
    

    

    x = 0
    for i in btn:
        
        pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),i)
        
        if i.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            fun[x]()
        x += 1
            
            
    
    np_c = npc(900,400)

    pygame.draw.rect(display ,(255,255,255) ,(225 ,1950, 90 ,90 ))
    
    pygame.draw.rect(display ,(255,255,255) ,(90 ,2060, 90 ,90 ))
    
    pygame.draw.rect(display ,(0,0,0) ,(p_x ,p_y ,150 ,90 ))
    
    
    
    
    
    
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(30)
    
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

When I click any button to scroll the background ,only the buttons flicker ,not character rectangle or other objects
Is it because of blit function?
Also how can I make this code more optimize?
Thanks for help

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

The button flicker, because you draw the background on top of the buttons in the `move` functions.

It is not necessary to redraw the background in the `move` functions. It is sufficient to update the variables `bgx` and `bgx2`. The background is automatically updated in the application loop:

```py
def move():
    global bgx
    global bgx2
    width = bg.get_width()
    bgx = (bgx - 50) % width
    bgx2 = bgx - width
    
def movex():
    global bgx
    global bgx2
    bgx = (bgx + 50) % width
    bgx2 = bgx - width
    
def move_2():
    global bgy
    global bgy2
    height = bg.get_height()
    bgy = (bgy - 50) % height
    bgy2 = bgy - height
    
def movey():
    global bgy
    global bgy2
    height = bg.get_height()
    bgy = (bgy + 50) % height
    bgy2 = bgy - height
```

If the background is shifted in the x and y direction, you need to draw th background 4 times:

```py
while not run:
    # [...]

    display.blit(bg, [bgx, bgy])
    if bgx != 0:
        display.blit(bg, [bgx2, bgy])
    if bgy != 0:
        display.blit(bg, [bgx, bgy2])
        if bgx != 0:
            display.blit(bg, [bgx2, bgy2])
```